# JPA Hibertane unidirectional one-to-one with shared primary key save parent first NO REVERSE

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I'v been searching internet for answer, but nothing was working for me. There is a lot of topics with similar cases but specific details are different in a way that make them unusable for me.

So I have two tables: t_item and t_item_info:

[image]

**item_id** field from *t_item_info* table references **id** field from *t_item* table. I'm using mysql db and **id** column form *t_item* is auto incremented

I need to make **unidirectional** one-to-one mapping in a specific way. Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "item_id")
    private ItemInfo info;
}
```

And other one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_item_info")
public class ItemInfo {
    @Id
    private Long itemId;

    private String descr;
}
```

So the point is that i need **Item** object to have a reference to **ItemInfo** object. NOT The other way!

```
Item -> ItemInfo   --YES
Item <- ItemInfo   --NO
```

The other thing is that i need parent (*Item*) id to become id for a child (*ItemInfo*)

For example I create *Item* object with null id and set it's *info* field with *ItemInfo* object which also have null id field. Like this:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "Some name",
  "info": {
    "itemId": null,
    "descr": "some descr"
  }
}
```

Then when *Item* object persists hibernate should generate id for parent(*Item*) object and set it as itemId field for child(*ItemInfo*).

I have been trying to achieve this with different hibernate annotations and I noticed that no matter how hard I tried Hibernate always seems to try to persist **child object first**. I noticed it in the logs when I turned sql logging on. insert into t_item_info always goes first (and dies because of null id :D)

**So the question is: Is it even possible to achieve this and if so what should I change in my code to do so**

I hope that what I'm trying to ask makes sens to you given my poor explanations =)

Comment: Did you try it with `optional = true` incase it is preventing `Item`  being stored first?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I just tried both true and false. As is it just says _"ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()"_, if i add `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on **id** field in **ItemInfo** it try's to persist it first saying `insert into t_item_info (descr) values (?)`. First message in "no generated value" case got me thinking that for some reason hibernate can't figure out that it needs to look for id in parent object? But how can I tell it to do so?

Comment: I am unable to understand the reasoning behind it too

Comment: If your relationship is mandatory then try to map it with ```@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", nullable = false)```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why people always insist the child object table in one-to-one associations should be the one with the foreign key is beyond me.

Anyway, as a workaround, since both objects share the `id` and the association is non-optional, you might as well declare the autogenerated key for the child object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_item_info")
public class ItemInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long itemId;

    private String descr;
}
```

and then use `@MapsId` for the parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId
    private ItemInfo info;
}
```

Note that this approach, will, in a sense, fool Hibernate into thinking it is the `Item` that should be treated as the child object. You have been warned.

Comment: Ok, this "hack" works like a charm. Thx u very much <3. But if i tried to make fk point from `t_item` to `t_item_info` like you suggested what would such mapping look like? And will it be possible to maintain my initial two points about `Item -> ItemInfo` link and parent id going to the child?

Comment: Actually, I realized that both in the case of your original solution and my suggested workaround, Hibernate should by default generate the FK from `Item` to `ItemInfo`, so I guess my comment doesn't really apply

Comment: I have been trying for the past hour without any success. Good to know this solution. Thank you

Comment: `@SecondaryTable` may possibly be a better solution here.

Comment: @AlanHay it may or may not make more sense. The benefit of the current solution is that `fetch = LAZY` works out of the box, and that `ItemInfo` is independently queryable. It all depends on the specific use case, though

Answer (score 2):

While there is an accepted answer here it looks to me like `@Secondary` table would be a better and more convenient solution: you may have 2 tables at the database level but I do not see any reason that that fact needs be exposed to any client code. There does not seem to be a lot of benefit to that? The following gives you a simpler API.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_item")
@SecondaryTable("t_item_info",  pkJoinColumns={
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="item_id")})
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Colulumn(name = "description", table= "t_item_info"")
    private String description;
}
```

API:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "Some name",
  "descr": "some descr"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I read so many topics and @SecondaryTable is a only working option for me!